# Qt: How do you handle focus changes for a QAbstractItemView

Tags: c++, qt, listview, user-interface, qt5

All I want to do, is know when the user presses ctrl + up arrow / down arrow to focus an item in the list. I expect that I can distinguish between a user focusing an item vs selecting an item.

I have an implementation of `QAbstractItemView` of which I have overridden

`::selectionChanged(const QItemSelection& selected, const QItemSelection& deselected)` as well as

`::currentChanged(const QModelIndex& current, const QModelIndex& previous)`

Its my understanding after reading https://doc.qt.io/archives/qtjambi-4.5.2_01/com/trolltech/qt/model-view-selection.html that if I focus an item with `ctrl + up arrow`, I will get a `currentChanged` event. If I select something via `up arrow`, I will get a `selectionChanged` event.

However, this is not what is happening. Pressing `ctrl + up arrow` is resulting in **both `selectionChanged` and `currentChanged`** to be fired. I have NO CONTEXT as to why either is fired once I get into those functions. When I'm in `selectionChanged`, I have no idea why I'm there. Was it because of a focus? was it because of a selection?

There is a thing that's maybe supposed to tell me which is `QItemSelectionModel.SelectionFlag`, but I apparently don't have access to those either.

So what's going on? Is this a bug? Again all I want to do is focus items in the list.

*qt version 5.9*

Comment: Recommendation: Do not transfer your frustration to your post, since it will be transferred to those of us who want to help you, besides that it distracts us and does not bring any information.

Comment: @eyllanesc, This recommendation is so well formulated, that it deserves to be incorporated into SO in some way.

Comment: its sound advice, appreciated.

Comment: I'll just point out that your documentation link looks really, really old. Maybe it's still accurate, but maybe it's not? I would start [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html).

Answer (score 2):

I tried to reproduce the issue described by OP.

Unfortunately, the OP didn't provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). So, I made one on my own:

```
// Qt header:
#include <QtWidgets>

class ListWidget: public QListWidget {

  public:
    ListWidget(QWidget *pQParent = nullptr): QListWidget(pQParent) { }
    virtual ~ListWidget() = default;
    ListWidget(const ListWidget&) = delete;
    ListWidget& operator=(const ListWidget&) = delete;

    virtual void currentChanged(
      const QModelIndex &current, const QModelIndex &previous) override
    {
      qDebug() << "currentChanged():" << previous << "->" << current;
      QListWidget::currentChanged(current, previous);
    }

    virtual void selectionChanged(
      const QItemSelection &selected, const QItemSelection &deselected) override
    {
      qDebug() << "selectionChanged():" << selected << "->" << deselected;
      QListWidget::selectionChanged(selected, deselected);
    }
};

void populate(QListWidget &qLst)
{
  const int n = 10;
  for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    new QListWidgetItem(QString("item %1").arg(i), &qLst);
  }
}

// main application
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // setup GUI
  ListWidget qLst;
  qLst.setSelectionMode(QListWidget::ExtendedSelection);
  populate(qLst);
  qLst.show();
  // runtime loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

Compiled in VS2017 with Qt5.13:

[image: Snapshot of testQAbstractItemViewCurrentChanged.exe]

Output:

```
Qt Version: 5.13.0
currentChanged(): QModelIndex(-1,-1,0x0,QObject(0x0)) -> QModelIndex(0,0,0x2adc4f38610,QListModel(0x2adc4f3a3a0))
```

I selected the first 5 items with <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd>:

```
currentChanged(): QModelIndex(0,0,0x2adc4f38610,QListModel(0x2adc4f3a3a0)) -> QModelIndex(1,0,0x2adc4f38a00,QListModel(0x2adc4f3a3a0))
selectionChanged(): (QItemSelectionRange(QModelIndex(0,0,0x2adc4f38610,QListModel(0x2adc4f3a3a0)),QModelIndex(0,0,0x2adc4f38610,QListModel(0x2adc4f3a3a0))), QItemSelectionRange(QModelIndex(1,0,0x2adc4f38a00,QListModel(0x2adc4f3a3a0)),QModelIndex(1,0,0x2adc4f38a00,QListModel(0x2adc4f3a3a0)))) -> ()
currentChanged(): QModelIndex(1,0,0x2adc4f38a00,QListModel(0x2adc4f3a3a0)) -> QModelIndex(2,0,0x2adc4f38a70,QListModel(0x2adc4f3a3a0))
selectionChanged(): (QItemSelectionRange(QModelIndex(2,0,0x2adc4f38a70,QListModel(0x2adc4f3a3a0)),QModelIndex(2,0,0x2adc4f38a70,QListModel(0x2adc4f3a3a0)))) -> ()
currentChanged(): QModelIndex(2,0,0x2adc4f38a70,QListModel(0x2adc4f3a3a0)) -> QModelIndex(3,0,0x2adc4f38ae0,QListModel(0x2adc4f3a3a0))
selectionChanged(): (QItemSelectionRange(QModelIndex(3,0,0x2adc4f38ae0,QListModel(0x2adc4f3a3a0)),QModelIndex(3,0,0x2adc4f38ae0,QListModel(0x2adc4f3a3a0)))) -> ()
currentChanged(): QModelIndex(3,0,0x2adc4f38ae0,QListModel(0x2adc4f3a3a0)) -> QModelIndex(4,0,0x2adc4f38f40,QListModel(0x2adc4f3a3a0))
selectionChanged(): (QItemSelectionRange(QModelIndex(4,0,0x2adc4f38f40,QListModel(0x2adc4f3a3a0)),QModelIndex(4,0,0x2adc4f38f40,QListModel(0x2adc4f3a3a0)))) -> ()
```

Then I moved the focus to `item 10` using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd>:

```
currentChanged(): QModelIndex(4,0,0x2adc4f38f40,QListModel(0x2adc4f3a3a0)) -> QModelIndex(5,0,0x2adc4f3f990,QListModel(0x2adc4f3a3a0))
currentChanged(): QModelIndex(5,0,0x2adc4f3f990,QListModel(0x2adc4f3a3a0)) -> QModelIndex(6,0,0x2adc4f3f6f0,QListModel(0x2adc4f3a3a0))
currentChanged(): QModelIndex(6,0,0x2adc4f3f6f0,QListModel(0x2adc4f3a3a0)) -> QModelIndex(7,0,0x2adc4f3f1b0,QListModel(0x2adc4f3a3a0))
currentChanged(): QModelIndex(7,0,0x2adc4f3f1b0,QListModel(0x2adc4f3a3a0)) -> QModelIndex(8,0,0x2adc4f3f840,QListModel(0x2adc4f3a3a0))
currentChanged(): QModelIndex(8,0,0x2adc4f3f840,QListModel(0x2adc4f3a3a0)) -> QModelIndex(9,0,0x2adc4f3f7d0,QListModel(0x2adc4f3a3a0))
```

This looks reasonable to me – no unnecessary calls to `selectionChanged()` as reported by OP.

To be sure, I compiled the same code in cygwin and tried again:

```
$ qmake-qt5 
Info: creating stash file /cygdrive/d/ds32737/Entwicklung/tests/Qt/QAbstractItemViewCurrentChanged/.qmake.stash

$ make && ./testQAbstractItemViewCurrentChanged
g++ -c -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -D_GNU_SOURCE -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -isystem /usr/include/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/usr/lib/qt5/mkspecs/cygwin-g++ -o testQAbstractItemViewCurrentChanged.o testQAbstractItemViewCurrentChanged.cc
g++  -o testQAbstractItemViewCurrentChanged.exe testQAbstractItemViewCurrentChanged.o   -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 
Qt Version: 5.9.4
currentChanged(): QModelIndex(-1,-1,0x0,QObject(0x0)) -> QModelIndex(0,0,0x60014b260,QListModel(0x6000df6b0))
currentChanged(): QModelIndex(0,0,0x60014b260,QListModel(0x6000df6b0)) -> QModelIndex(1,0,0x60014ba60,QListModel(0x6000df6b0))
selectionChanged(): (QItemSelectionRange(QModelIndex(0,0,0x60014b260,QListModel(0x6000df6b0)),QModelIndex(0,0,0x60014b260,QListModel(0x6000df6b0))), QItemSelectionRange(QModelIndex(1,0,0x60014ba60,QListModel(0x6000df6b0)),QModelIndex(1,0,0x60014ba60,QListModel(0x6000df6b0)))) -> ()
currentChanged(): QModelIndex(1,0,0x60014ba60,QListModel(0x6000df6b0)) -> QModelIndex(2,0,0x60014bb20,QListModel(0x6000df6b0))
selectionChanged(): (QItemSelectionRange(QModelIndex(2,0,0x60014bb20,QListModel(0x6000df6b0)),QModelIndex(2,0,0x60014bb20,QListModel(0x6000df6b0)))) -> ()
currentChanged(): QModelIndex(2,0,0x60014bb20,QListModel(0x6000df6b0)) -> QModelIndex(3,0,0x60014bc30,QListModel(0x6000df6b0))
selectionChanged(): (QItemSelectionRange(QModelIndex(3,0,0x60014bc30,QListModel(0x6000df6b0)),QModelIndex(3,0,0x60014bc30,QListModel(0x6000df6b0)))) -> ()
currentChanged(): QModelIndex(3,0,0x60014bc30,QListModel(0x6000df6b0)) -> QModelIndex(4,0,0x60014bd20,QListModel(0x6000df6b0))
selectionChanged(): (QItemSelectionRange(QModelIndex(4,0,0x60014bd20,QListModel(0x6000df6b0)),QModelIndex(4,0,0x60014bd20,QListModel(0x6000df6b0)))) -> ()
currentChanged(): QModelIndex(4,0,0x60014bd20,QListModel(0x6000df6b0)) -> QModelIndex(5,0,0x60014be10,QListModel(0x6000df6b0))
currentChanged(): QModelIndex(5,0,0x60014be10,QListModel(0x6000df6b0)) -> QModelIndex(6,0,0x60014bf00,QListModel(0x6000df6b0))
currentChanged(): QModelIndex(6,0,0x60014bf00,QListModel(0x6000df6b0)) -> QModelIndex(7,0,0x60014bbb0,QListModel(0x6000df6b0))
currentChanged(): QModelIndex(7,0,0x60014bbb0,QListModel(0x6000df6b0)) -> QModelIndex(8,0,0x60014c120,QListModel(0x6000df6b0))
currentChanged(): QModelIndex(8,0,0x60014c120,QListModel(0x6000df6b0)) -> QModelIndex(9,0,0x60014c210,QListModel(0x6000df6b0))
```

So, again I cannot reproduce. The reported events are comparable to the one I got with VS2017.

Please, note that I have installed Qt5.9.4 on cygwin – the version OP claims to have.

Comment: Ahh I see. So it really is supposed to only be calling currentChanged when focus is changing. I should've mentioned that I'm not using QListWidgets. I'm not sure if that matters. I'm using QStyledItemDelegate. Not sure if that matters. I guess I'll try and contrive something in a small example

Comment: @JoshSanders Try to reproduce your issue with a [mcve] as small as possible. I used `QListWidget` to keep code fpr populization etc. minimal. If this is an issue of `QAbstractItemView` it shouldn't make a difference. I'm not sure under what circumstances `QStyledItemDelegate` plays a role (but IMHO it shouldn't).

Comment: @JoshSanders What OS/platform are you on?